# Hibernate (Spring JPA): @ManyToOne JoinColumns (which are an EmbeddedId) are null

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, many-to-one, joincolumn

I didn't see my error and after a research on stackoverflow and Google I think the code should be correct. But Hibernate (spring-boot-starter-data-jpa 2.2.4) still fill the JoinColumns with `null`.

Here is my `OneToMany` class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tablea", schema = "")
public class TableAEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7890327260188587351L;

    @EmbeddedId
    private MyId id;
    
    @OneToMany(cascade = ALL, mappedBy = "tableA", orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<TableBEntity> tableBentries;
    
    // Getter + Setter
}
```

My `EmbeddedId` class:

```
@Embeddable
public class MyId implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8267953052238233498L;

    @Column(name = "id")
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "iddate")
    private Date iddate;

    @Column(name = "idint")
    private BigInteger idint;
    
    // Getter + Setter
}
```

And finally my `ManyToOne` class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tableB", schema = "")
public class TableBEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4648090658471459969L;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "iddate", referencedColumnName = "iddate"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "idint", referencedColumnName = "idint")
    })
    private TableAEntity tableA;
    
    // Some other attributes
    
    // Getter + Setter
}
```

As you may see I want to use the attributes (`id`, `iddate` and `idint`) as a combined primaray key in both tables.

When I create the `TableAEntity` object I add several `TableBEntity` objects to the `tableBentries` attribute. And for every `TableBEntity` I set the reference to the `TableAEntity` (attribute `tableA`). And of course the `MyId` (attribute `id`) object is filled.

After saveing the `TableAEntity` object, Hibernate also stores all `TableBEntity` but the fields `id`, `iddate` and `idint` (all JoinColumn's) are `null`.

Any idea?

Comment: Maybe you can use 'private MyId id' as JoinColumns.
I guess it automatically persist all three fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `@Id` in my `TableBEntity` causes the problems. If I moved it to another attribute, it works.